# Find JSON string from the HTML

Tags: java, html, regex

I have an HTML String provided below:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head><title>Breadcrumb Admin</title>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like to extract the JSON string inside this tag using regex:

```
{

   "restaurant": {

   }
}
```

I have this Java code which is not working:

```
        String restaurants = null;

        String findMe = "\\{\"restaurant\":\\[(.*)\\]\\}";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(findMe);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(response.getBody());
        
        if (m.find()) {
            restaurants = m.group(0);
        }
```

Whats the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String htmlString = "<script>\n" +
                "    _preloaded = {models: [], collections: [], notification: {}};\n" +
                "    _preloaded.models.push(\n" +
                "\n" +
                "     {\n" +
                "        \"restaurant\": {\n" +
                "            \"id\": \"abcd-efgh-ijkl\",\n" +
                "            \"created_at\": \"2020-12-31\",\n" +
                "            \"cashier_payments\": []\n" +
                "        }\n" +
                "     }\n" +
                ");\n" +
                "</script>";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\([^)]*\\)");//. represents single character
Matcher m = p.matcher(htmlString);

if(m.find()){
      String matchJson = m.group(0);
      String onlyJson = matchJson.substring(1, matchJson.length()-1).trim();
      System.out.println(onlyJson);
}
```

Output:

```
{
        "restaurant": {
            "id": "abcd-efgh-ijkl",
            "created_at": "2020-12-31",
            "cashier_payments": []
        }
     }
```

Comment: Not working perhaps because we have many tags like the "restaurant". Can we use the "restaurant" inside the regex?

Comment: The current regex extracts anything within parenthesis. I assumed there was only one such json.

Comment: Well, I should have info that this is a dummy HTML doesn't contain all the business data. I updated the HTML in the question. Would you please mind to change your answer.